# How to find diameter of a set in metric space C[0,1]

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How to find the diameter of the Set $A$=$\{{t^n}:n\in N\}$ in $C[0,1]$ with metric $d(x,y)=sup_{t\in [0,1]}|x(t)-y(t)|$

I don't know how to approach this question.

Comment: Did you try to compute the distance between elements in this set?

Comment: @Mark I'm comfortable with finding diameter in $R^n$ by drawing the graph but I'm not sure how to draw the graph of this set as it contains a sequence. So, I failed to find a approach.

Comment: Is $N$ the natural numbers with or without $0$? Notice that if $m>n$ then $\left|x^{n}-x^{m}\right| = x^{n}-x^{m}$ for $x \in \left[0,1\right]$, so you can find the distance with calculus technique, then it is a question of maximizing a function of $m$ and $n$

Comment: @SoumyajoyDas Well, I hope you at least agree that $d(t^n, t^m)\leq 1$ for all $m,n$. So the diameter can't be bigger than $1$. To show it can't be smaller than $1$, let $\epsilon>0$. For a large enough $n$ we have $(1-\epsilon)^n<\epsilon$. So at the point $x=1-\epsilon$, the values of $t$ and $t^n$ differ by at least $1-2\epsilon$, and so $d(t, t^n)\geq 1-2\epsilon$. This is the idea, now try to write it formally. Actually, you can draw the graph of these functions if that helps you get an intuition.

Comment: Got it thank you @Mark

Comment: @Mark: That seems like an answer to me. What more is there to say?